# subqueries on same table optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a statistic report project to show top counts of searching keywords, the table has about 50m records.

The table(simplified):

```
+----------------------+--------------+
| Field                | Type         |
+----------------------+--------------+
| acct                 | varchar(5)   |
| branch               | varchar(2)   |
| page_name            | varchar(20)  |
| access_time          | datetime     |
| query_input          | varchar(500) |
+----------------------+--------------+
```

`page_name` can be 3 values: `'search'` `'detail'` or `'cart'`

What I need is each type of `page_name` grouped by `query_input` and count the rows, in descending order, with limits, within one query. at first I simply let hibernate fetch all the records and then handle them in java, but query takes too long, even though I'm using stateless session.

To reduce the size of the data returned from hibernate, I tried this

```
(SELECT page_name, query_input, count(*) FROM table_name WHERE acct='XXXXX' AND page_name='search 'GROUP BY query_input ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 100)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ... AND page_name='detail' ...)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ... AND page_name='cart' ...)
```

but this would cause database to loop table 3 times, is there a way to rephrase the query so it only loops table once, but get the same result I want?

For example, without limit:

```
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
| page_name            | query_input  | count(*)|
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
| search               | CCC          | 10      |
| search               | EEE          | 8       |
| search               | AAA          | 1       |
| search               | BBB          | 1       |
| detail               | DDD          | 12      |
| detail               | FFF          | 11      |
| detail               | HHH          | 1       |
| detail               | GGG          | 1       |
| cart                 | III          | 6       |
| cart                 | JJJ          | 4       |
| cart                 | LLL          | 1       |
| cart                 | KKK          | 1       |
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
```

with limit 2:

```
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
| page_name            | query_input  | count(*)|
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
| search               | CCC          | 10      |
| search               | EEE          | 8       |
| detail               | DDD          | 12      |
| detail               | FFF          | 11      |
| cart                 | III          | 6       |
| cart                 | JJJ          | 4       |
+----------------------+--------------+---------+
```

**Update**

I'm getting the feeling that this is unsolvable, because I realized that I'm actually trying to 'select from a table **by** its ordering', and to MySQL,  ordering is not taken into consideration on select... Am I correct

Comment: I'm not quite sure of your question, but you can provide more than one column name to a `group by` clause, which will group by the combination of the two columns. If you try `GROUP BY page_name query_input` does that get close to what you want?

Comment: @Jerry This will make results sort by page_name but I need to eliminate a portion of rows of each 'sub-group' beforehand

Comment: So you want the two most common query inputs for each page_name?

Comment: @Jerry that's correct

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I haven't come up with anything better than you already have. I'll keep pondering, though. It might be worth checking if making `page_name` an enum improves your speed.

Comment: See the tag `[greatest-n-per-group]` (n=100 in your case)

Comment: @Rick James Thanks! This is the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `in` operator:

```
SELECT page_name, query_input, count(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE acct='XXXXX' 
  AND page_name IN ('search', 'detail', 'cart') 
GROUP BY query_input 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: This will order the count(*) only but not within each page_name, there could be 99 'search' and only 1 'cart',  what I want is each page_name of top 100

Comment: In the provided query, are the condensed lines not the identical to the complete line other than the `pageName` filter value?